# SQL Row Select Based on Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to find a way to select a row based on condition in MSSQL, I have two rows

| SO | LineNumber | LineStatus | OrderQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 | 4 |
| A | 1 | 80 | 4 |

How should I write in SQL -- First Select the row with line status 80 and SUM(OrderQty), if there is no such row with Line Status = 80 then select Line Status= 10 and SUM(OrderQty).

Can you please suggest something, Thanks in advance

I have tried AND OR condition, not working as expected. Can you kindly suggest something to help me.

Comment: Please add more rows to the sample data. Do you want to sum() by order? All items in the order or just some of them?

Comment: Can you add the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we assume that you are grouping by SO? If so, something like this should work:

```
select 
  SO
, coalesce(SUM(case when LineStatus=80 then OrderQty end)
          ,SUM(case when LineStatus=10 then OrderQty end)) as SumOrder
from Table_1
group by SO
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked as expected for me. It was not working because I was grouping by line number and status, but grouping by Item did the trick,

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a join for such a thing:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM table1 t1
   JOIN table2 t2 
      ON t2.id = (
       SELECT TOP 1 id
       FROM table2 innerT2
       WHERE innerT2.condition = condition
   )
```

Comment: Your join condition is rather weird.  You didn't reference `t1` column at all in the `ON` condition

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
select LineStatus, SUM(OrderQty) as SumOrder
from Table_1
group by LineStatus 
order by LineStatus desc
```